# "The value is never used" pointer re-assignment C++

Tags: c++, pointers, scope, variable-assignment

I'm refactoring this bit of code:

```
struct GameState {
    PieceState piece;
}


//create local copy from piece, modify it, and only when its VALID copy it back!
void update_game_play(GameState *game, const InputState *input) {
    PieceState piece = game->piece;

    //'left' from perspective of the game
    if (input->dleft > 0) {
        --piece.offset_col;
    }
 
    if (is_piece_valid(&piece, game->board, WIDTH, HEIGHT)) {
        game->piece = piece;
    }
}
```

This code takes a `piece` struct, and only when it's valid it's re-assigned to the `GameState` struct.

But in my refactored code the assignment gives me a warning that `the value is never used` in the last line, inside the if-statement:

```
    //create local copy from piece, modify it, and only when its VALID copy it back!
    void update(Piece *pieceTmp, Board *board) override
    {
        auto piece = *pieceTmp;

        //'left' from perspective of the game
        if (input.dleft > 0) {
            --piece.offset_col;
        }

        //test with dummy if statement
        if (true) {
            pieceTmp = &piece; //"the value is never used"
        }
}
```

The way I understood it, is that I'm dereferencing the pointer to a object, changing the object properties, and then assign the address of the object to my original pointer? What's going on?

Comment: You want `*pieceTmp = piece`.

Comment: `pieceTmp = &piece;` does not "copy it back". `pieceTmp` is passed by value, so changes to it are not reflected in the calling code. Moreover, `&piece` is a dangling reference because `piece` goes out of scope at the end of `update`. I think you meant `*pieceTmp = piece`.

Answer (score 1):

The function accepts the first argument by value.

```
void update(Piece *pieceTmp, Board *board) override
```

That is it deals with a copy of the value of the original argument.

So the new value of the pointer

```
pieceTmp = &piece;
```

is used nowhere in the function (and in the caller).

Another problem is that you are trying to assign the address of a local variable that will not be alive after exiting the function. So after exiting the function the pointer (if it will be passed by reference) will have an invalid value.

Instead of this statement

```
pieceTmp = &piece;
```

you could write for example

```
*pieceTmp = piece;
```